# play music randomly from a folder onclick android

Tags: android, audio

I have code for changing image of button onclick and then revert it back after 3sec. it also plays a sound when clicked.

```
    package com.example.btn;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        Handler mHandler; // global instance
        Runnable your_runnable; // global instance

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        public void yolo(final View view) {

            if (view == view) {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn1);//Change to this when clicked
                final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.z);//this mp3 is compulsary
                final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.r);//this mp3 should be random
                mp1.start();   //play mp3
                mHandler = new Handler();
                your_runnable = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn2);//Revert back to this after timer

                    }

                };

                mHandler.postDelayed(your_runnable, 3000L);// 3sec timer

            }
        }
    }
```

what i want is to play random music when that button is clicked, not just play the assigned music. (in this line final MediaPlayer mp1=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.r);//this mp3 should be random)

i think there are two ways of achieving this, 1.play music randomly from a specific folder.
2. play music randomly from assigned music through code.

please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the ids of music resources in one array and randomly select one to play , like the following:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{R.raw,x, R.raw.y};

public void someFunc() {
    Randome r = new Random(arr.length);
    MediaPlayer mp = MeadiaPlayer.create(getbaseContext(), arr[r.nextInt()]);
    //your rest code
}
```